# How to get all custom token of a firebase user?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I create many custom token by admin

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const claims = {};
const UID = ""; //
admin.auth()
.createCustomToken(UID, claims)
.then((customToken) => { 
   // new token is customToken
});
```

How I can get all custom token of UID?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The tokens expire once used. You can store them in db after creation if you need to

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't have an API to return all tokens it has minted. If you need such a thing, you should create your own database of tokens (and properly secure access to it).

Comment: thank you guys !